# Pandas UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encoding

Working with pandas and every time a "special" char like: é
comes up it throws an Encoding error.
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r'movies analysis\movie_metadata.csv',encoding='utf-8')
print(df.loc[df['title_year'] == 2015])
```

and this is the error i'm getting:

```
 File "D:\ANACONDA\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 645: character maps to <undefined>
```

there are many threads on the subject but none offer a solution that worked for me.

Comment: You are trying to print a character that isn't supported by your environment (terminal, IDE...). Your options are writing to a file (eg. with `pd.write_csv`) or switching/configuring terminal for UTF-8 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i ended up doing is "normalizing" all the characters into ascii.
It's not ideal but it works for me:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFD', Data_U_Want_To_Normalize).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

so in the case of a letter like `é` it gets turned into `e`.

Answer (score 1):

add `export LANG=zh_CN.utf8` or `export LANG=us_EN` to your bashrc or your shell script, it worked for me
my  script is:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel(f) 
# there are chinese in my file
```