When i run inversetest.py in wpf app, I get error on predict model
When I run python code in c#, I get error on line of predict model but it run in python well. I used any way such as python.net, ironPython, Process,... but it did not work:
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string scriptPath = @"E:\TrainedModels\inversetest.py";
            var result = RunPythonScript(scriptPath);

        }

        public static string RunPythonScript(string scriptPath)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "\"C:\\Users\\PC 4\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe\"",
                Arguments = scriptPath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                //WorkingDirectory = @"E:\TrainedModels"
            };

            using (Process process = new()
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo
            })
            {
                process.Start();

                var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    return $"Error: {error}";
                }
                return output;
            }

Ocurre error when predict model:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\TrainedModels\inversetest.py", line 32, in <module>
    pre_Down=valve_model_Down.predict(X)


My code in python:

Temp_data=pandas.read_csv("invtest.csv")
## Import Dataset

x = Temp_data[['thickness','Percu1','Percu2','Percu3','Percu4','Percu5','Percu6','Percu7','Percu8','Percu9'
           ,'Percu10','Percu11','Percu12','Percu13','Percu14','Percu15','Percu16','Percu17'
           ,'Percu18','Percu19']]

X = x / 95

L_mid = np.linspace(0, 68, 68)

## Load ANN model
valve_model_Down = pickle.load(open('inverse_Quant_Down.sav','rb'))
valve_model_Middle = pickle.load(open('inverse_Quant_Mid.sav','rb'))
valve_model_Up = pickle.load(open('inverse_Quant_Up.sav','rb'))

#prediction
pre_Down=valve_model_Down.predict(X)
pre_Middle=valve_model_Middle.predict(X)
pre_Up=valve_model_Up.predict(X)

Can someone help me to solved it?

Please explain what you mean by 'it does not work'.  Explain what exactly it is you're doing.  What is your sample like?  what does inversetest.py look like?

Output of inversetest.py after get input from csv type and predict those is an image.jpg, but when it is executed in c#, does not output!!! and got above errors

likely that there's a character in your save file that python doesn't like.   Take a look at this question and see if it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307384/pandas-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character

I changed the ProcessStartInfo and worked successfully
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new()
            {
                FileName = "python.exe",                    
                Arguments = scriptPath,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                RedirectStandardError = false
            };

